# Querying for Project Permissions on Sharepoint 2019 using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, csom, psi, sharepoint-2019

This is my first post here, and I hope someone can help me. Please feel free to ask for more information about my question if needed.

I am currently working on a project to migrate a Sharepoint 2010 solution to Sharepoint 2019, and right know I am handling the development part of the project. I am quite new to Sharepoint development, so I have some questions that might seem basic.

I am trying to replicate one feature from this old project and create a new one in this new Sharepoint 2019 project. The method consists of querying the Project's Permissions through PSI, using the Security WCF service. (with the "ReadProjectCategory" method)

However, I have read online that the PSI is discontinued in 2019, so I am trying to implement this method using CSOM, but I can't find the correct method to look for [this information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN5Ie.png) (the image shows exactly where the data is).

Can someone please help? I can't find anywhere how to get this data over CSOM or OData.

The page url is: //Sharepointurl/PWA/_layouts/15/PWA/views/ProjectPermissions.aspx?_projectUID=[ProjectGUID]

Thank you!